# Limiting non-dfs usage per data node

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am facing a strange problem due to Hadoop's crazy data distribution and management. one or two of my data nodes are completely filled up due to Non-DFS usage where as the others are almost empty. Is there a way I can make the non-dfs usage more uniform?
[I have already tried using dfs.datanode.du.reserved but that doesn't help either]

**Example for the prob:** I have 16 data nodes with 10 GB space each. Initially, each of the nodes have approx. 7 GB free space. When I start a job for processing 5 GB of data (with replication factor=1), I expect the job to complete successfully. But alas! when I monitor the job execution, I see suddenly one node runs out of space because the non-dfs usage is approx 6-7 GB and then it retries and another node now runs out of space. I don't really want to have higher retries because that's won't give the performance metric I am looking for.

Any idea how can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your input isn't being split up properly. You may want to choose a different InputFormat or write your own to better fit your data set. Also make sure that all your nodes are listed in your NameNode's slaves file.
Another problem can be serious data skew - case when big part of data is going to one reducer. You may need to create you own partitioner to solve it.

Comment: The data-blocks of the input data is split quite uniformly across the nodes, but during the reduce phase, some of the nodes are overloaded with non-dfs data.

Comment: yup... this actually solved the problem... somewhat... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not restrict non-dfs usage, as far as I know. I would suggest to identify what exactly input file (or its split) cause the problem. Then you probably will be able to find solution. 
Hadoop MR built under assumption that single split processing can be done using single node resources like RAM or disk space.

Comment: Thanks! I thought so. Is there a way I can identify the root-cause of the splitting problem?
Just giving some more details on the job processing-i) The data-blocks of the input data are split quite uniformly (dfs-usage & num- blocks) among the nodes, the problem occurs during the reduce phase of the job on some nodes
ii) My input data is in XML format, is it better to use Mahout's XMLInputFormat?